# Is it possible to install Ruby 3 on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, ruby

I’ve been trying to install Ruby 3 on my old Mac running 10.6 Snow Leopard using ruby-build. I can’t figure out why it’s failing. I couldn’t find any Ruby documentation on whether or not Mac OS X 10.6 is even supported or not. Is it even possible to install Ruby 3 on a Mac running 10.6?

Comment: Googling `snow leopard ruby 3` shows me multiple results. I don't have the know-how to validate them, but this one seems promising: [https://github.com/murphy99/skeleton_app/wiki/Installing-Ruby-on-Rails-on-Mac-OS-10.6-Snow-Leopard](https://github.com/murphy99/skeleton_app/wiki/Installing-Ruby-on-Rails-on-Mac-OS-10.6-Snow-Leopard)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks, but that’s not quite the same thing. Ruby 3 is relatively new. The link you posted is about Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: If it’s failing to be installed then there is an error message, but you haven’t been provided the error message, can you provide us that error message?